# Using refs to view functional component state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to write a form with multiple Input components. They consume a validation function, message and other data as a props and update their state accordingly to show errors and feedback to the user. Below them i have a submit button that is only enabled when the form is valid; something like this:

```
<form>
  <Input .../>
  ...
  <Input .../>

  <button disabled={isFormValid}>submit</button>
</form>
```

I learned a lot of ways to make this work without components. But I was thinking about this component alternative where I'm only interested in each component validity, value and a reset function. Using refs i would be able to calculate the validity of the form with something like this:

```
isFormValid = ![Input0ref,...,InputNref].some(input => input.current.isValid === false)
```

Values could be accessed using refs too, the same if I want to reset the inputs.

This can be done using forwardRef and useImperativeHandle but I read that these should not be overused.

Is this a justifiable use of forwardRef and useImperativeHandle or am I going against the spirit of the framework?

Comment: could build a validation check inside Input then pass it the function to be run on validation. Instead I like having the Input be seperate from validation and pass an error prop string instead. And run the validation in the parent on submit or something. Then if there is an error in that Input I would pass it into the error prop.

Comment: In this case the validation is done on every keystroke so the user gets an immediate feedback. That is handled by the component already and is not the problem. The problem is the recovery of the Component state with a ref, IF it is a problem in the first place.